# is this normalization correct

Tags: database-design, normalization

is this normalization correct for UNF to 3NF
[image]

Comment: You list 5 table and only have two.   Invoce_Table should not have CustomerNo and address.

Comment: Normalization to 3NF involves functional dependencies.  Please provide the functional dependencies which hold between the attributes in order to evaluate if each table is or is not in the NF claimed.  Also, there is no difference between what you have for UNF and 1NF that I can see.

Comment: I suspect it is not in 3NF due to the Shipper likely being repeated and not dependent on the key.